# Error: Run configuration app is not supported in the current project. Cannot obtain the application ID

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Everytime I open my project in Android Studio, this error appeared:

```
Error: Run configuration app is not supported in the current project. Cannot obtain the application ID.
```

When I click `Sync project with Gradle Files`, after the syncing process, this error disappeared. **However** when I reopen the project or restart Android Studio, this error appears again.

I know `Sync project with Gradle Files` can do the trick, but I don't want to do it everytime I open my project, I have tried to downgrade Android Studio, however it seems not working.

My environment:

- Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1
- Gradle 7.5.1
- Android Gradle Plugin 7.3.0

Some thing interesting is that each time I start Android Studio, an IDE error pop up:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find root module data: xxxx-xxxx
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.VariantSwitcher.getAndroidModules(VariantSwitcher.kt:248)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.VariantSwitcher.getSelectedVariants(VariantSwitcher.kt:261)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.VariantSwitcher.findAndSetupSelectedCachedVariantData(VariantSwitcher.kt:128)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectStartupActivityKt.attachCachedModelsOrTriggerSync(AndroidGradleProjectStartupActivity.kt:198)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectStartupActivityKt.access$attachCachedModelsOrTriggerSync(AndroidGradleProjectStartupActivity.kt:1)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectStartupActivity.runActivity(AndroidGradleProjectStartupActivity.kt:105)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runStartupActivity(StartupManagerImpl.kt:312)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runActivityAndMeasureDuration(StartupManagerImpl.kt:293)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runActivityAndMeasureDuration$default(StartupManagerImpl.kt:288)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$runPostStartupActivities$1$2.run(StartupManagerImpl.kt:256)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.doRun(DumbServiceImpl.java:395)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.updateFinished(DumbServiceImpl.java:387)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.TrackedEdtActivityService$TrackedEdtActivity.run(TrackedEdtActivityService.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:214)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$200(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:196)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:805)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeLater$4(ApplicationImpl.java:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:82)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:131)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:47)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue$FlushNow.run(FlushQueue.java:187)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:891)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:760)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:818)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:805)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:492)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

I have dependend on another private module I wrote my self in **settings.gradle**

```
includeBuild('external/xxxx-xxxx') {
    name "xxxx-xxxx"
    dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('com.xxxx.xxxx:xxxx:1.0.0') using project(':xxxx-xxxx')
    }
}
```

Maybe is my submodule's issue or a bug in Android Studio/Gradle? Other project does not have this issue.

Answer (score 31):

In my case, the package name was missing from the Manifest file (weird because I just created the project and it should have been there by default) but I added it and now it's working.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.example.name">
```

Answer (score 20):

In my case what is helped:

1. Close IntelliJ Idea project (or Android studio)
2. Remove .idea folder in the root of the project
3. Open the directory of the project, and initialize it again.

Comment: Oh wow it works. It really works. I can't believe it, it works.

Answer (score 3):

For me problem was that I selected **release** build variant.

Fix was just to go to Build variants and select **debug**.