# Error: Run configuration app is not supported in the curent project. Cannot obtain the package

Tags: debugging, configuration

[?????????[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO4sG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO4sG.png)

> i cannot run code ?

i select nothing in debloy and launch then restart program

Comment: I found the solution from an answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74148896/4564088

+1 for correctly writing the error message with the typo

Answer (score 0):

The reason is applicationId is not defined in the `android/app/build.gradle` or you may have defined the value through a compile time variable but the value is empty.
for example you may have configured the applicationId via dart environment variables in VSCode, but if you try to run the app in Android studio because you may have forgotten to define dart environment variables the value is empty:

try to change highlighted application Id to a hard coded value and try again.
[image]